# Return object with updated association in Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Using Sequelize and MySQL, updating an object including the associated object it has. Everything updates fine but I can't get the new associated object to return. If I do another GET request it's the new one but I need it to come back on the response after an update.

I'm trying to just reload that contact object before return.

The object looks like this:

```
{

    "id": 1,

    "details": "some task details",

        "contact": { //associated object

            "associatedId": 1,

            "name": "Mike",

       }

}
```

This is what I'm trying

```
db.task.findOne({
  where: {
    id: taskId,
    userId: req.user.get('id')
  },
  include: [db.contact]
}).then(
  function(task) {
    if (task) {
      return task.update(attributes);
    } else {
      res.status(404).send();
    }
  },
  function() {
    res.status(500).send();
  }
).then(
  function(task) {
    if(task) {
      res.json(task);
    }
  },
  function(e) {
    res.status(400).json(e);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is `returning: true` :

```
return task.update(attributes,{
  returning: true,
  plain: true
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it is still returning the old association, it looks like that only works in Postgres I forgot to mention i'm using MySQL.

Comment: Then you need to update the record first and then you need to fetch it again and return that the only way with mysql and sequelize